# Using JSON data that does not have "x/y" as its key

Tags: javascript, json, rickshaw

I am new to this world of *JSON* and Graphs, first time use of Rickshaw.

In the examples it uses *JSON* data that has an x and y as its key:

```
{ x: 1910, y: 92228531 }
```

My data has the following key, values:

```
{"sampletime":"2013-05-11 11:47:54","samplevalue":"4.39"}
```

Is it possible to tell Rickshaw to use my data in that format or maybe there is a way to convert this *JSON* data on the fly so to speak?

UPDATE:

Changed the SQL to:

```
select sampletime as "x", samplevalue AS "y" from rn_qos_data_0011 order by sampletime desc limit 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

Changed SQL/PHP to:

```
$sql = mysql_query("select sampletime as \"x\", samplevalue AS \"y\" from rn_qos_data_0011 order by sampletime desc limit 10;");

$results = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
   $results[] = array(
      'x' => strtotime($row['x']),
      'y' => (float)$row['y']
   );
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($results);
```

Note the conversion to epoch time and float was required.